# Using a custom Wordpress query to call 5 most recent posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to pull the 5 most recent posts of a custom post type using a WP_query. Does the code below look correct? And do I need to use wp_reset_postdata at the end?

```
<?php 
  $args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'webinar_post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
  );
  $most_recent = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if( $most_recent->have_posts() ) ?>

  <?php while( $most_recent->have_posts() ) : $most_recent->the_post() ?>
   <div class="webinar">
    <h2><?php echo get_the_title(); ?> </h2>
    <h3><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></h3>
    <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
</div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: What's not working?  What does it currently do?  wp_reset_postdata() is only used if you want to run another WP_Query after this this code.  Does the code return an error because you are missing a ":" after the have_posts() if function at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `wp_reset_postdata()` unless you are using `WP_Query` again in the same page. Usage of `wp_reset_postdata()` is need to set the post data back

*Example*

```
<?php
// The 1st Query
$args = [
    'post_type'  => 'webinar_post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
];
$most_recent = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $most_recent->have_posts() ) {
    // The Loop
    while ( $most_recent->have_posts() ) { $most_recent->the_post();
        // your code
    }
    // Restore original Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
}

// Updating `$args`
$args['orderby'] = 'post_title'
$args['order'] = 'ASC'

/* The 2nd Query */
$most_recent2 = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $most_recent2->have_posts() ) {
    // The 2nd Loop
    while ( $most_recent2->have_posts() ) { $most_recent2->the_post();
        // your code
    }
    // Restore original Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>
```